# Selenium IDE: Firing off an Ajax call whenever the play button is pressed

Tags: ajax, jquery, selenium, selenium-ide

I'd like to fire off an Ajax call whenever the user clicks the play button in Selenium IDE.  The jQuery $.ajax function would be even better.  Is there a way to do this?

After 20 minutes searching online, I haven't found anyone trying to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the Selenium commands that evaluates JavaScript code. For example the `waitForCondition` command executes a JavaScript snippet until the evaluation of the last expression is true. Note that you can skip the first two part if your test page already has jQuery.

### Load the jQuery library into the page

#### JavaScript snippet

```
(function(window) {
    var script = window.document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    window.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
})(selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow());
1 == 1; // put something that evaluates to "true" here to make sure that our code runs only once
```

#### Selenium command

```
<!--Inject jQuery-->
<tr>
    <td>waitForCondition</td>
    <td>(function(window) { var script = window.document.createElement(&quot;script&quot;); script.src = &quot;http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js&quot;; script.type = &quot;text/javascript&quot;; window.document.getElementsByTagName(&quot;head&quot;)[0].appendChild(script); })(selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow()); 1==1;</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
```

### Validate that jQuery has been downloaded and ready to use

#### JavaScript snippet

```
typeof selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().jQuery == 'function'
```

#### Selenium command

```
<!--Validate jQuery-->
<tr>
    <td>waitForCondition</td>
    <td>typeof selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().jQuery == 'function'</td>
    <td>60000</td>
</tr>
```

### Make an ajax call

#### JavaScript snippet

```
(function(window) {
    window.jQuery.ajax('http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery');
})(selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow());
1 == 1;
```

#### Selenium command

```
<!--Make an AJAX call-->
<tr>
    <td>waitForCondition</td>
    <td>(function(window) {window.jQuery.ajax('http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery'); })(selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow()); 1 == 1;</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  I'll try next time I'm at work and report back.